# Why can't I use ManagedProperty inside a function ?

Tags: java, jsf, web

I want to make the DB object be created only when it's required, so I want to do something like this

```
public class Data {

public List<Group> getGroups(){
    List<Group> MyList=new ArrayList<Group>();
    Connection conn=null;
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{myConnection}")
myConnection getCon;

}
```

But that doesn't work, Instead I have to do it like this

```
public class Data {
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{myConnection}")
myConnection getCon;
public List<Group> getGroups(){
    List<Group> MyList=new ArrayList<Group>();
    Connection conn=null;


}
```

Why can't I make a managedProperty inside the function ? 
I thought about it and it should be okay to be outside since it'll be created when I create the object but is there anyway to make it inside the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use [ManagedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html) annotation inside the function . It can be only used on a field. See the definition of the ManagedProperty below

```
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Target(value=FIELD)
public @interface ManagedProperty
```